# React Native - Expo - Local Schedule Notification Throwing Multiple Notifications at Once Instead of Single on Android

Tags: notifications, react-native, expo

I am trying to create water reminder app with notification feature once in every hour.
I have implemented notifications with scheduleLocalNotificationAsync. My implementation works as expected in IOS but in Android when I open the app, the app sending 12 notifications at the same time instead of sending them one by one at scheduled time.

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  this._sendNotifications();
};

_sendNotifications = async () => {
  // Not to create duplicated notifications first cancel all notifications
  await Notifications.cancelAllScheduledNotificationsAsync();

// beginning of notification part
const localnotification = {
  title: 'Water Reminder',
  body: "Don't forget to drink water!",
  android: {
    sound: true,
  },
  ios: {
    sound: true,
  },
};

// get the current date
let currentDate = Date.now();
currentDate = new Date(currentDate);

// get the day, month and year from current date to create time to schedule
let year = currentDate.getFullYear();
let month = currentDate.getMonth();
let date = currentDate.getDate();

// then create unix epoch number for eact date with number from notification section
// then we call notification function with each timestamp (not1)
if (this.state.switchStatus === false) {
  await Notifications.cancelAllScheduledNotificationsAsync();
} else {
  // Notification for nine
  if (this.state.otherSwitchStatus.nine === true) {
    let not0 = new Date(year, month, date, 9);
    not0 = Date.parse(not0);
    const schedulingOptions0 = { time: not0, repeat: 'day' };
    // call the function to send notification at 9:00
    await Notifications.scheduleLocalNotificationAsync(localnotification, schedulingOptions0);
  }

  // Notification for ten
  if (this.state.otherSwitchStatus.ten === true) {
    let not1 = new Date(year, month, date, 10);
    not1 = Date.parse(not1);
    const schedulingOptions1 = { time: not1, repeat: 'day' };
    // call the function to send notification at 10:00
    await Notifications.scheduleLocalNotificationAsync(localnotification, schedulingOptions1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I understand what is going on with the code.

Since as you can see in my code, independent of current time of the day, I am calling scheduleLocalNotificationAsync for 15 times (starting from 09:00 to 23:00, with daily repeat option). However when I open Notification screen at 12:40 I receive 4 notifications immediately (for one each 09:00, 10:00, 11:00 and 12:00).

I guess expo immediately calling notification function for 4 passed times. This is not the case for ios but it is happening in Android. I guess it needs to be fixed in expo side.

Until then I solved the issue by checking current hour and compare it with time to be scheduled and if it is passed, I schedule it for tomorrow.

```
let hour = currentDate.getHours();
// I changed the code below
// let not0 = new Date(year, month, date, 9) 
// to this
let not0 = new Date(year, month, hour > 9 ? date + 1 : date, 9);
```

I also created an issue expo github. 
https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/3946